Opening YouTube from WhatsApp stacks YouTube on top of WhatsApp
Since a few weeks now whenever I open a YouTube link from WhatsApp, the YouTube app is stacked on top of WhatsApp, instead of it switching to the YouTube app as a separate app.
This is unhelpful because now I can't use the recents screen to go back to WhatsApp, but I have to click Back once to exit the video and once more to exit the home screen on YouTube to come back to the WhatsApp conversation.
Can I have the old behavior back? How?
I'm using Android 14 on a Galaxy S23+
This doesn't happen when, for example, I open Chrome by clicking a link from WhatsApp.

I can't reproduce the issue for now, though I think I've observed this before. I think this is related to YouTube's Picture-in-Picture. Maybe try going to YouTube's app info, selecting Picture-in-Picture, and then switching it off. (reference for different app)

@AndrewT. That didn't work unfortunately
